# jQuery get params of onerror event

Tags: jquery, bind, parameters, onerror

**Js code:**

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno)
    {
        alert("Ошибка:"+message +"\n" + "файл:" + source + "\n" + "строка:" + lineno);
    };
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(window).bind('error', function (event) 
    { 
        console.log(event); 
        //event.data
        //.message ?
        //.lineno ?
        //.source ?
    }
);
```

How get "message", "lineno" and "source" values from jQuery-event? 
Value event.data is null.

Comment: Try `console.log(arguments)`

Comment: I not find need params in event object

Comment: Note: A jQuery error event handler should not be attached to the window object.... http://api.jquery.com/error/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I saw this note, but code working and I thought I might have the method to obtain the parameters.